# AngularJS routeParam not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, mean-stack

I have url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/details/59567bc1de7ddb2d5feff262
```

and I want to get the parameter `id`

```
59567bc1de7ddb2d5feff262
```

But for some reasons routeParam always returns `undefined`

My controller is:

```
task.controller('ctrla',  function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout, $routeParams){
    $scope.first = 1;
    console.log($routeParams);        
});
```

routes :

```
task.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/details/:id', {
      templateUrl: "details.html",
      controller: "ctrla"
    })

});
```

any help will be a life save.

Comment: how are your routes defined?

Comment: i update my question with the routes definition please give it a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the route urls as mentioned below,

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      template: "HI this is home Screen",
      controller: 'ctrla'
    })
    .when('/details/:id', {
      templateUrl: "template.html",
      controller: 'profileController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    })
}]);
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Waso01mzPn3ZN7H1m0I?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer and the DEMO

Answer (score 1):

If yu have route deinition defined as

```
$routeProvider.when('/details/:id', {
      templateUrl: "partial.html",
      controller: "ctrla"
    })
```

Then in controller you should get its value as

```
task.controller('ctrla',  function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout, $routeParams){
    $scope.first = 1;
    console.log($routeParams.id);

});
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but still give me undefined!!

Comment: And are you able to see the view correctly? also are you using $locationProvider.html5mode (as there's no # in your url)?

Comment: I didn't know That Thank you for your answer